# SQL Server @@Identity

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

I do not understand @@Identity. What does this do exactly? I have tables with their Identity Specification set to Yes and Identity increment set to 1. I am reviewing code from the database programmer and I found the following:

```
DECLARE @CustomerID int,
    INSERT INTO Customers
    (Name, Login, Password, IsActive,)
    VALUES('University', NULL, NULL, 1,)
    SET @CustomerID = @@IDENTITY
```

but in other places after insert, she did not include `@@IDENTITY`. For example:
in the same code she has:

```
INSERT INTO Meters
(Name, Type, SiteID, CustomerAccountID)
SELECT Sites.Name + ' ' + Type, ID, ID, NULL
FROM Sites
CROSS JOIN MeterTypes
WHERE ProjectID = @ProjectID
AND tblMEP_MeterTypes.ID IN(1, 3, 13)
```

Can anybody tell me when to use `@@IDENTITY`? I thought it should be at the end of every insert statement. By the way the table above (Customers) it has a column called ID and it is a primary key field and cannot be Null! How is this valid? should not it be like:

```
DECLARE @CustomerID int,
    INSERT INTO Customers
    (ID, Name, Login, Password, IsActive,)
    VALUES(1, 'University', NULL, NULL, 1,)
    SET @CustomerID = @@IDENTITY
```

Comment: That is not my question! I read that, and looked online but I am not getting anywhere with that.

Comment: Why do we use them places and we do not in other places? I am sorry I know this is annoying but I swear if I know I would not ask.

Comment: Pretend you've never heard of @@IDENTITY. You should use SCOPE_IDENTITY when you need it. And you are learning backwards IMHO - you shouldn't be asking "ooh, what is this function name, can I use this somewhere?" you should be asking "ok, I have this situation where I need to get the last identity value generated in a table, which function should I use?"

Comment: A common problem in database programming is adding related sets of rows, e.g. a customer and their meters. When you add the customer a new identity value is assigned to `CustomerId`. In order to tie the meter records to that customer you need to get the new `CustomerId` and store it in the appropriate meter rows. That is the problem that `@@Identity` was intended to solve. Avoid it like the plague and use either `Scope_Identity()` or, better yet, learn about the generally useful `OUTPUT` clause. When you add a meter, but don't immediately need the `MeterId`, then you don't bother with it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because in the second block of code she did not care what IDENTITY value was generated. Perhaps in the first code sample it was being used to return to the client or to insert into a related table afterward.

And forget about @@IDENTITY. SCOPE_IDENTITY() is much safer and the OUTPUT clause can be useful too.